# how do diabetics keep their kidney healthy?

Tags: diabetes, health-education

I understand diabetes can cause kidney problems. Are there any treatments or other preventative measures that can reduce or prevent kidney problems?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! I recommend taking [the tour](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/tour) and getting your [informed badge](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/informed). I've edited your question to help it sound less like a question looking for personal medical advice (which is [off topic here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). If I missed something important about your question, please feel free to edit it again yourself!

Comment: Thanks for editing question.I have no issue ...

Comment: Here is an article in the use of B1 and the kidney. So perhaps you can add it to your research. I think a diabetic may want to discuss this with her doctor. There is also a fat soluable form, benfotiamine. https://www.dsm.com/markets/pharma/en/news/dsm-pharma-blog/vitamin-b1-and-diabetic-patients.html

Comment: PS the article says 47% of adult Chinese have diabetes! I hope this is a misprint. The above is not suggested as a cure, mind you. But it may help with some of the medical problems associated with diabetes.

Comment: Diabetes causes many problems. It is a simplication, but it is not a terrible idea to view some of these problems as Beriberi-like.  B1 or Thiamine deficiency disease.  Just keep this gently in mind. The Answers  below are correct and more complete than this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following are the recommendations from the Joslin Center for preserving renal function in diabetes mellitus

> Tight control of blood glucose levels (A1C less than 7 percent)
>
> Tight control of blood pressure: aim for lower than 130/80
>
> Control of lipids: LDL (“bad”) cholesterol should be less than 100 mg/dl, HDL (“good”) cholesterol should be above 50 mg/dl and triglycerides should be less than 150 mg/dl
>
> No cigarette smoking
>
> Blood pressure-lowering drugs, such as ACE inhibitors or angiotensin receptor blockers (ARBs), are effective in protecting the kidney from damage if you have signs of diabetic kidney disease

https://www.joslin.org/info/how-to-prevent-kidney-disease.html

Answer (score 5):

Diabetes does cause kidney problems, and is the leading cause of end stage renal disease in industrialized world (see Cecil Medicine, Chapter 126, Diabetes and The Kidney).  Though neither fully prevents the development of kidney problems entirely, [tight glucose control](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=9742976) together with [blood pressure control with an ACE-inhibitor or ARB](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17054288) slow the progression of kidney disease and reduce all cause mortality in diabetics. Early on, this is the mainstay of prevention and treatment (tight glucose control plus RAAS inhibition), but reduction of other risk factors plays an important role as well. Stopping smoking, exercising, and losing weight (while maintaining tight glucose control) are important steps (see Cecil Medicine, Ch 126, again).